# Use Directory.Build.props or targets file from subdirectory

Tags: msbuild, git-submodules, csproj

We have few solutions that reside in different git repositories, that use a shared project as a git submodule (one repo linked to another repo as a subdirectory in the "parent" repo). We also want to have a common **Directory.Build.props** file (or something similar) that is shared between the different solutions, containing some common definitions. Because we want it to be shared between all of the repositories, it makes sense to put it also inside the shared repo (submodule). The problem is that a submodule is always a subdirectory and therefore it can't affect the other projects in the containing solutions.

I searched for a way to include an MSBuild file (Directory.Build.props, or *.targets) file from one another, but I couldn't find a simple way to do it, nor a clear documentation on how to create a custom *.targets file.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: MSBuild files include other MSBuild files with [`Import`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/import-element-msbuild?view=vs-2022).

Answer (score 1):

From the question I'm assuming that [MSBuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild?view=vs-2022) is largely unfamiliar.

MSBuild files are XML and the simplest valid MSBuild file is:

```
<Project />
```

Running this file directly with MSBuild will be an error because there are no `Target`s defined but it is a valid file and it can be used as the basis of a file to be `Import`ed.

[`Import`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/import-element-msbuild?view=vs-2022) is used to include the content of an MSBuild file into another MSBuild file.

MSBuild will search for and automatically import files that are named either `Directory.Build.props` or `Directory.Build.targets`. See "[Customize the build by folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-by-directory?view=vs-2022)". Note the section on "[Search scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-by-directory?view=vs-2022#search-scope)". MSBuild will search up the directory tree. The subdirectory for the submodule will not be searched.

Note the section on "[multi-level merging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-by-directory?view=vs-2022#use-case-multi-level-merging)" which shows how to set up a chain of `Directory.Build.props` files and a chain of `Directory.Build.targets` files.

There is an example `Import` that can be used in a `Directory.Build.props` but the `Import` can be generalized to the following:

```xml
<Import Project="$([MSBuild]::GetPathOfFileAbove('$(MSBuildThisFile)', '$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)../'))" />
```

The `$(MSBuildThisFile)` property will be the name of the current file. Using this `Import`, a `Directory.Build.props` file will look for a `Directory.Build.props` file and a `Directory.Build.targets` file will look for a `Directory.Build.targets` file.

The `GetPathOfFileAbove` function will return an empty string if no file is found and `Import` will fail with an error if the value of the `Project` attribute is an empty string. The highest level file should not try to import from above. As a guard, a `Directory.Build.props` file and a `Directory.Build.targets` file that don't import can be created in the root of the repo. The two files may have the content shown above, i.e. `<Project />`, because they don't need to do anything except terminate the import chain. The number of files in the chain and the level at which the files appear can be changed and the chain will always terminate in the repo root.

This may all seem like a tangent but these files in the repo root can look for and import the submodule's files.

Example:

1. In the repo's root create a file named `Module.props`.
2. Edit the file to have the following content:

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- Directory path for a submodule named 'shared'. -->
    <SharedModuleDir>shared</SharedModuleDir>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

3. In the repo's root create a file named `Directory.Build.props`.
4. Edit the file to have the following content:

```
<Project>
  <Import Project="Module.props" />
  <Import Project="$(SharedModuleDir)\$(MSBuildThisFile)" Condition="Exists('$(SharedModuleDir)\$(MSBuildThisFile)')" />
</Project>
```

5. Copy the `Directory.Build.props` and name the copy `Directory.Build.targets`.